# ARRAY_AGG without duplicates

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In `PostgreSQL` database I have table which has columns like `ITEM_ID` and `PARENT_ITEM_ID`.

```
| ITEM_ID | ITEM_NAME | PARENT_ITEM_ID |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 1       | A         | 0              |
| 2       | B         | 0              |
| 3       | C         | 1              |
```

My task to take all values from these columns and put them to one array. In the same time I need delete all duplicates. I started with such SQL query but what the best way to delete duplicates?

```
SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(ITEM_ID || ',' || PARENT_ITEM_ID)
FROM
    ITEMS_RELATIONSHIP
GROUP BY
    ITEM_ID
```

I want such result:

```
[1,0,2,3]
```

Right now I have such result:

```
|{1,0}|
|{2,0}|
|{3,1}|
```

Comment: Hint:  `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT)`.

Comment: Hello! Can you check my post one more time please. Right now I have all ids (`item_id` and `parent_item_id`) not in one array. At the end of the post you can notice example. How to fix this problem? Just `DISTINCT` is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one array of all item IDs, don't group by `item_id`.  Something like this might be what you want:

```
select
    array_agg(item_id, ',') as itemlist
from
    (
        select item_id from items_relationship
        union
        select parent_item_id from items_relationship
    ) as allitems;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method to get the parent item ids in with the other item ids:

```
select array_agg(distinct item_id)
from items_relationship ir cross join lateral
     (values (ir.item_id), (ir.parent_item_id)) v(item_id);
```

This unpivots the data using a lateral join and then aggregates.